# How do I get a reference to a window and then cast it to a windows form

Tags: c#, interop

So, I am trying to get a reference to a specific window which I happen to know to be a Windows form object in memory. Unfortunately it is private. So I have to go a round-about way to do work on it.

I am trying this to get it to work:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    internal static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
    IntPtr hWnd = FindWindow(null, "Fiddler - HTTP Debugging Proxy");
    Form Fiddle = Form.FromHandle(hWnd);
```

Unfortunately I am getting this error.

Error   CS0236  A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'Test.hWnd'

Interop with C++ windows calls is not my strong point. I am having a hard time understanding what this trying to tell me. And how to achieve this.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the interop.  You can't use the value of `hWnd` from within another field initializer.  Put those calls in the class's constructor or whatever method will use the handle.

Comment: Can you give an example in code as an answer?

Comment: I am sorry, buddy, but this type of coding error I have never seen before in my normal C# coding. Not a clue how to fix it.

Comment: Oh. I get it now.  internal static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);  Is a method declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DLL import and the FindWindow() need to be put outside of the method.  FindWindow is a method declaration.

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    internal static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
    void method()
    {

        IntPtr hWnd = FindWindow(null, "Fiddler - HTTP Debugging Proxy");
        Form Fiddle = FromHandle(hWnd) as Form;
    }
```